Celery tasks aren't sent to celery worker
I'm trying to build web using flask, celery and redis. I'm developing in wsl2 ubuntu and set the environment by docker. Flask, celery and redis are in same docker container.
So, my problem is that celery tasks are not working.
Any logs are printed in celery worker terminal so I wonder that if celery is not connected with redis or not.
I set my celery like this.
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379/0',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379/0')
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']) # celery 선언
celery.conf.update(app.config) # flask와 celery 동기화

I think there's no problem here. And I also tested redis with ping, it works.
I already set the docker container port too 5000 for web, 6379 for redis.
ah, finally my task flow is like this.
When the user send the post request, collected infos are send to celery task.
How can I fix the prob..?
I tested redis with ping. Already checked the docker container port export.

@KenWhite Sorry it was my first time using stackoverflow. I appreciate your comment.

Much better title. Thanks!
